# Customize location of title and p-value in ggsurvplot()

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am unable to cutomize the locatin of the title to top right as I am able to do in the case of Pvalue.

The following code :

```
ggsurvplot(fit, # survfit object with calculated statistics
           data = paad_GeneName, # data used to fit survival curves
           pval = TRUE, # show p-value of log-rank test
           pval.coord = c(1,0.07), # p-value location
           pval.size = 6.5, # adjust p-value size
           title.coord = c(1,0),
           legend.title = "", 
           legend = "none",
           xscale = "d_y", # convert time as days to years in x-axis
           break.x.by = 365.25, # break X axis in time intervals by years as integers
           xlab = "Time (years)", # customize X axis label
           palette = c("red","darkgreen"))
```

generates the following plot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ku0W.jpg)

Can someone explain if there is a way to adjust the location of title to top right?

Thanks a lot.
Manav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change p-value position, you may want to try this:
Since you do not have a reproducible example, I used `lung` data from `survival`

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

p <- ggsurvplot(fit, # survfit object with calculated statistics
  # data = paad_GeneName, # data used to fit survival curves
  pval = TRUE, # show p-value of log-rank test
  pval.coord = c(365.25 * 2, .95), # p-value location
  pval.size = 6.5, # adjust p-value size
  legend.title = "",
  legend = "none",
  xscale = "d_y", # convert time as days to years in x-axis
  break.x.by = 365.25, # break X axis in time intervals by years as integers
  xlab = "Time (years)", # customize X axis label
  palette = c("red", "darkgreen")
)

p
```

[image]

To change the plot title position, I would try to use ggplot `theme()`. I am not sure about `title.coord()`.

```
p$plot +
    labs(title = "My title")+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust =1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked the way I wanted it to.